# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.ApiResponse

Tags: android, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

I made a few changes to my android application, and now I'm getting this.  I'm thinking it might be caused by updating the autogenerated ApiGateway SDK that I'm using in my app.  But maybe it's something else?  I'm not even sure where to start debugging.

`build.gradle:`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.johndoe.supercoolsoftware"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'app/libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.14.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.22'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.2.22'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognitoidentityprovider:2.2.22'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.2.22'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-apigateway-core:2.2.22'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    //used for API Gateway SDK generated classes
    compile files('libs/Api-alpha-0.51.jar') #<- autogenerated SDK
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: I've just updated my generated SDK and got the same error. Did you find a solution?

Comment: It looks like the newly generated api sdks have `ApiResponse execute(ApiRequest var1);` as the first method. This seems to be what is crashing the app

Comment: @TedEriksson No I haven't found a solution yet, but I haven't had anymore time to look into it since I posted this.  If I find something I'll be sure to put an answer here (and you do the same too please :D)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay I figured it out.  AWS just updated their Android core.  So now when you build it's using a newer version (v2.3.2 now) where the old one was v2.22.2.  Once I updated my android application to use v2.3.2 by changing my gradel file, everything worked.

```
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.3.2'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.3.2'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognitoidentityprovider:2.3.2'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.3.2'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-apigateway-core:2.3.2'
```

Comment: Thanks... after all the googling, only this solved the problem.